# Activate and Deactivate buttons in SharePoint Online solution gallery are disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I have created a standard Team Site (Classic), added some lists and pages and taken the site template (.wsp). I have used this template to create sites in several SPOnline tenancies. However, in one tenancy, activate button is disabled for this template feature and so I am not able to create the site using this template.

I have compared the site collection features and site features of site collections between the tenancies (working vs non-working) and they are same. Also, I went to "SharePoint admin center" and compared the settings and they are also same.

Please let me know what change I need to do in my tenancy/site collection/template so that it can be activated.

Thanks

Comment: Try disabling the 'include assembly in package' option when you import your .wsp into Visual Studio. Then recreate the package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have directly taken the site template and did not use the Visual Studio for this.